# how to de-capitalize titles in action bar

Tags: android, android-xml

am creating an action bar using Android API level 21, lollipop, and I've got to the point where I have to add a text button in the actionbar, I've added it successfully, but the text says: "SUBMIT" I want it to show "Submit".

Any ideas ? I've tried fiddling around with the styles with no luck here's my code:

```
 <style name="myStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185548

Answer (score 2):

**Important:** This will only work on API 14+ as `textAllCaps` was introduced in API 14.

In your API 14+ style specify this:

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.MyApp.Widget.ActionBar.Menu</item>
```

Then define the actual font style derived from appropriate parent.

```
<style name="TextAppearance.MyApp.Widget.ActionBar.Menu" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

If you don't use appcompat-v7 library replace `AppCompat` parent with `Holo` on API 14+ and `Material` on API 21+ (and prefixing the style with android:). Ie:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.MyApp.Widget.ActionBar.Menu" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Tested on Kitkat.

**Pre-ICS**

I am not able to test it but you might want to try. Please report the result.

In your pre-API 14 theme specify

```
<item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.MyApp.Widget.ActionBar.Menu</item>
```

Add the following to the action bar menu style:

```
<item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on every device. Definitely not working on my SGS2 with API 16